# Combine where - like - where_in

Tags: php, codeigniter, where-clause, sql-like, where-in

Let's say I have a model in CI returning what user(s) need to ..

```
$find = 'something';
$id_user = Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 5 [2] => 20 [3] => 21 ) ;
```

So, I have to put that in here but something goes wrong ..

```
    public function find_pr_by_user ($find,$id_users) {
        $this -> db -> where_in ('req_by_id'.$id_users || 'check_by_id',$id_users || 'approve_by_id',$id_users);
        $this -> db -> where ("(ref_no LIKE '%$find%' || pr_title LIKE '%$find%' || req_date LIKE '%$find%')");
        $query = $this -> db -> get ('pr_data') ;
        return $query -> result () ;
    }
```

I get error Array to string conversion; input I have is from `$find` and `$id_users` that can be anything. I expected this logic, give me all array from table `PR_DATA` which is have `%$find%` on column `ref_no` or `pr_title` or `req_date` but only have `$id_users` *(1 or 5 or 20 or 21) in column `req_by_id` or `check_by_id` or `approve_by_id`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What error message do you get? And please clarify your input and expected output

Comment: Yeah unfortunately you cannot use `where_in()` that way. Your parameter is suited for `where()`, but not `where_in()`. You will have to use a workaround to make it happen. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is under assumption that you need parenthesis in the first `where_in()` in your code.

Unfortunately, CodeIgniter does not fully support parenthesis with Active Record. Therefore you will have to use `where()` with more complex SQL syntax in it.

```
public function find_pr_by_user ($find,$id_users) {
    $id_users_glued = implode(",",$id_users);
    $this->db->where('(req_by_id IN (' . $id_users_glued . ') || check_by_id IN (' . $id_users_glued . ') || approve_by_id IN (' . $id_users_glued . '))');
    $this->db->where("(ref_no LIKE '%$find%' || pr_title LIKE '%$find%' || req_date LIKE '%$find%')");
    $query = $this->db->get('pr_data') ;
    return $query->result () ;
}
```

In CI's Active Record, this is how the syntax will be treated:

The **FIRST WHERE** will be treated as: `WHERE (req_by_id IN ($id_users_glued) || check_by_id IN ($id_users_glued) || approve_by_id IN ($id_users_glued)`

The `$id_users_glued` will produce something like `1,2,3,4,5`

The **SECOND WHERE** will be treated as: `AND (ref_no LIKE '%$find%' || pr_title LIKE '%$find%' || req_date LIKE '%$find%')`

**Note:** I haven't tested the code because I don't have your db structure. Let me know if it's not working.

Comment: thanks dude .. my 2x24 hours fixed in 10 minutes ... #LOL

Comment: glad to help. I faced that issue before as well :)